# How to avoid JQuery class selector?

Tags: jquery, animation

I just started learning JQuery.

My code:

```
 $(document).ready( function(){
   $('.img').click(function(){
     $('.img').animate({
       opacity: 0.25,
       left: "+=50",
       height: "toggle"
     }, 5000, function(){                                                                                             
               // Animation complete.
   });
  })
});
```

here .img is an image and I am doing an animation on that. But what I want is I don't want to specify each class type like `.img`. All elements I have on the page(images, p,border) can go through the same animation. so I expect something like

`$(this).click( function{ $(this).animate(.........`

Is it possible by putting something like `this` we don't have to specify the exact class? I tried with this, it is not working.

Comment: Yes, `this` inside the event handler will refer to the element that triggered the event.

Comment: @j08691 how shall I modify the above code to make it work?I added this like above, it is not working.

Comment: You'd specify the elements in the click selector, then in the function use `this`. Ex: `$('.img, .something, .somethingelse').click` and in the handler code, `$(this).animate(`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".img").click(function(){
    $(this).animate( ... );
});
```

Comment: Perfect. And in the spirit of OP's request for not passing in class names, just use the same class name for every element you want to animate (e.g. `.animate`).